# How to concat bytes to str like Python 2 allows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working on a bufferoverflow exercise (specifically stack4 from protostar),
I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import struct
# EBX -> RRRR
# ECX -> QQQQ
# EBP -> SSSS

# legit ret addr: 0xbfff f5bc

ECX = struct.pack("I", 0xbffff5c0)    # +4: BFFF F5C0
EBX = "EEBX"
EBP = "EEBP"

payload = "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHHIIIIJJJJKKKKLLLLMMMMNNNNOOOOPPPP"
payload += ECX+EBX+EBP  # Like: QQQQ RRRR SSSS
payload += 'TTTTUUUUVVVVWWWWXXXXYYYYZZZZ'

print(payload)
```

When I try to run it, it raises with can't concat bytes to string. The error occurs from the `payload += ECX`... line where it tries to concat str to bytes (the ECX var). In python 2 it allows to do so.

I need to be able to parse ASCII and HEX values so that the payload will work.
How do I concat these two objects?

Comment: Make sure they're either all `bytes` or all `str`. Use `b''` byte literals or `.decode` `bytes` into a `str`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to work with binary data, always work with bytes and not strings:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import struct

ECX = struct.pack("I", 0xbffff5c0)
# note the b in front of the string literal
EBX = b"EEBX"
EBP = b"EEBP"

payload = b"AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHHIIIIJJJJKKKKLLLLMMMMNNNNOOOOPPPP"
payload += ECX+EBX+EBP
payload += b'TTTTUUUUVVVVWWWWXXXXYYYYZZZZ'

print(payload)
```